# Bean not autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I currently have an application-context.cml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
  default-autowire="byType">


  <context:annotation-config />
  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <bean class="app.bl.facade.impl.DishFacadeImpl" />
```

And I am attempting to autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private DishFacade dishFacade;

public List<Dish> getEvents() {
    System.out.println(dishFacade);
    return dishFacade.getAll();
}
```

The result I get printed out is `null`, I'm unable to figure out why though.

Comment: is the class within which your DishFacade in also gets created by Spring?

Comment: I believe you need to add `<context:component-scan base-package="my_base_package_name.*" />`

Comment: where is `<context:component-scan base-package="app.bl.facade.*" />`

Comment: Do you have a setter method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your package is `app.bl.facade` you have to place this tag in your `application-context.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.bl.facade" />
```

Above XML tag will perform an auto scanning. Each class which should be created as a bean is annotated with a correct `stereotype` annotation like `@Component` (for general bean) or `@Controller` (for a servlet controllers) or `@Repository` (for DAO classes) or `@Service` and these classes should be placed under the same base package `app.bl.facade`.

If above criteria is met, then spring will automatically find all of these and create a bean for each one.

Comment: Why he needed this ?, As he is using annotation-config. what he needed is to have the @Autowiring over the setter of DishFacade OR either to have the Setter of DishFacade

Comment: Spring bean will be autowired to other spring managed beans only, unless an external setter or constructor properties are set to perform the process of injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your default auto-wiring mode is "byType". For this type of autowiring, class type is used. So there should be only one bean configured for this type in the spring bean configuration file.

So you should be auto-wiring `DishFacadeImpl` and not `DishFacade` which, I think, is the interface.

[This](http://www.journaldev.com/2623/spring-bean-autowire-by-name-type-constructor-autowired-and-qualifier-annotations-example) might help.